# How to add TAG to a already committed in Git and Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash

I already committed but missed to TAG it,Is it possible to add `TAG` to already committed code i am  using `Git` and `Bitbucket` So far i tried with the below git  bash commands

```
1. git tag "v1.0" fd5j6dj
2. `git tag -a v1.2 9fceb02 -m "Message here"`
```

Still no luck can you please suggest anything which would work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can tag it later and run `git push --tags` to update the tags to the remote repo, so you never miss it. But in some teams, to push tags  may need permission.

Comment: good it worked for me,but if i want to remove a particular tag from master how to do it

Comment: @AbhijitChakra `git push --tags <remote> :<tag_name>` like to delete a branch in the remote repo, '<space>:<branch>'

Comment: git tag -d <tagName> then git push origin :remote/tags/<tagName>'worked for me

Comment: @AbhijitChakra you are right. My sample command keeps the local tags.

Answer (score 2):

Now, suppose you forgot to tag the project at v1.2, which was at the  commit. You can add it after the fact. To tag that commit, you specify the commit checksum (or part of it) at the end of the line for this case its **6fcub07**:

```
$ git tag -a v1.2 6fcub07
```

You can see that you’ve tagged the commit:

Answer (score 1):

You can add tag from Bitbucket GUI. Provided you have Bitbucket server 4.7 or higher.

Reference : https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Tags-on-Bitbucket-server/qaq-p/523879

Answer (score 0):

You can tag it in the bitbucket GUI. 
when you browse to the commit section and open the commit you want to tag there is a tags section in the top right of the page. If you press the + button you can add a tag to a commit.

We are running the following version:
Atlassian Bitbucket v4.8.3

Comment: Mine does not have this option in the GUI :-(